# How to get the highest 4 tuple values?

Tags: python, tuples

I am trying to get the highest 4 values in a list of tuples and put them into a new list. However, if there are two tuples with the same value I want to take the one with the lowest number.

The list originally looks like this:

```
[(9, 20), (3, 16), (54, 13), (67, 10), (2, 10)...]
```

And I want the new list to look like this:

```
[(9,20), (3,16), (54, 13), (2,10)]
```

This is my current code any suggestions?

```
sorted_y = sorted(sorted_x, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True)[:5]
sorted_z = []
while n < 4:
    n = 0
    x = 0
    y = 0
    if sorted_y[x][y] > sorted_y[x+1][y]:
        sorted_z.append(sorted_y[x][y])
        print(sorted_z)
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
    elif sorted_y[x][y] == sorted_y[x+1][y]:
        a = sorted_y[x]
        b = sorted_y[x+1]
        if a > b:
            sorted_z.append(sorted_y[x+1][y])
        else:
            sorted_z.append(sorted_y[x][y])
        n = n + 1
        print(sorted_z)
        print(n)
```

Edit: When talking about lowest value I mean the highest value in the second value of the tuple and then if two second values are the same I want to take the lowest first value of the two.

Comment: isn't `(67,10)` highest one in above tuple?

Comment: What do you mean "highest 4"? If two `tuples` have the same values, then neither of them can be lower...

Comment: `if there are two tuples with the same value` - Do you mean `if there are two tuples with the same second value`?

Comment: @pistol2myhead yes that is correct I mean two tuples with the same second value.

Comment: @gmds if two tuples have the same second value then I want to take the one with the lowest first value.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar I am going by the second value as highest in a tuple

Comment: You probably want to initialise `n, x, y` before the while loop and not inside. Initialised inside they are reset to `0` on every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `groupby`?

```
from itertools import groupby, islice
from operator import itemgetter

data = [(9, 20), (3, 16), (54, 13), (67, 10), (2, 10)]
pre_sorted = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

result = [sorted(group, key=itemgetter(0))[0] for key, group in islice(groupby(pre_sorted, key=itemgetter(1)), 4)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[(9, 20), (3, 16), (54, 13), (2, 10)]
```

Explanation:

This first sorts the data by the second element's value in descending order. `groupby` then puts them into groups where each `tuple` in the group has the same value for the second element.

Using `islice`, we take the top four groups and sort each by the value of the *first* element in ascending order. Taking the first value of each group, we arrive at our answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
l = [(9, 20), (3, 16), (54, 13), (67, 10), (2, 10)]
asv = set([i[1] for i in l])  # The set of unique second elements
new_l = [(min([i[0] for i in l if i[1]==k]),k) for k in asv]
```

**OUTPUT** :

```
[(3, 16), (2, 10), (9, 20), (54, 13)]
```